# Super Simple Boolean Function— what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, function

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work: 
A super simple function that just needs to return true or false:

```
<?php
function check_for_header_images() {
    if ( file_exists('path/to/file') && file_exists('path/to/file'))  
 return true;
}
?>
```

It will not return true:

```
<?php
if(check_for_header_images()) {
    // do stuff
}
?>
```

…doesn't do stuff:

```
<?php
if(!check_for_header_images()) {
    // do stuff
}
?>
```

…does do stuff.

The conditions I've set for the function SHOULD return true.  If I take that same exact if statement and just do this:

```
<?php
    if ( file_exists('path/to/file') && file_exists('path/to/file'))  {
        //do stuff
    }
?>
```

It works.
Do I just not understand how to write a function?

Comment: You should use `return file_exists('path/to/file') && file_exists('path/to/file');` in your function instead; otherwise, if the condition is false, nothing is returned.  I don't know if that's the problem, though.

Comment: Do the `file_exists` arguments are hard-coded (e.g.: `path/to/file`) or are they actually variables (e.g.: `$foo`)?

Comment: If any function is meant to return some value (i.e. not void), make sure it returns something valid in every exit point. Also it's good practice to have a `return <default-value>` just before the function end. For example, in your case you should have `return false` as [Brad Christie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/298053/brad-christie) mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. All of your answers make perfect sense, and I've tried both methods, and still can't get either to return true when they're supposed to.  When I copy the if(file_exists) and use them directly, it works perfectly, but not inside the function.  I just don't get it.  I must have a typo that I just haven't spotted.  netcoder—the arguments were hard-coded.  Just for the sake of it, I tried variables as well, and got the same results.  Curious where you're going w/ that question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  function check_for_header_images() {
     if ( file_exists('path/to/file') && file_exists('path/to/file'))  
       return true;
     return false; // missing the default return when it's false
  }
?>
```

or you could do:

```
<?php
  function check_for_header_images() {
    return ( file_exists('path/to/file') && file_exists('path/to/file'));
  }
?>
```

also, the `!` in your if statement means opposite. that means `if (!false)` is true, and `if (!true)` is false

Comment: Thanks. Tried both and still can't get it to work! Yes about the '!'… I just included that example to reenforce that it's returning false when it's supposed to be returning true.  At this point I can only assume I have some extra character or typo or something in there, but I'm not getting any errors.  Grr.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer anyway, because I know you're right!

Comment: @Kerri: Are the "/path/to/file" values hard-coded or are they variables? If it's the latter it may be variable scope. For grins, try adding [`global $path1, $path2;`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) above the if statement and see if it works any better.